# How to check whether server is accessible?

Tags: c#, .net

**Directory.Exists(@"\MyServer\Images")** command works correctly while 
**Directory.Exists(@"\MyServer")** doesn't.

Can you suggest me a "Directory.Exists" equivalent to check the accessibility of servers.

**Please don't suggest to ping the server**, because sometimes ICMP is blocked by server firewall and the PING command doesn't work. And don't refer to the similar questions where using the PING command can be acceptable by question posters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast way to check if a server is accessible over the network in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663212/fast-way-to-check-if-a-server-is-accessible-over-the-network-in-c-sharp)

Comment: How do you plan to access the server? If you want to access an UNC path, check whether this path is accessible. If you want to communicate over TCP, check whether you can establish the connection on the port.

Comment: How to check whether path is accessible? I can't use the PING command

Comment: Tim, the link you suggested above offers using the PING command that I can't use as I said in my question.

Comment: Why do you repeat the question?

Comment: Thorsten, because the author of the "duplicate" question might be satisfied with using the PING command while I am not.

Comment: How about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152647/how-to-quickly-check-if-unc-path-is-available

Comment: Well, you could clarify your question as to *how* you want to access the server. Then we could maybe provide better answers.

Comment: @Murat: it seems to be the best option. Apart from that it shows also different ways. It's a duplicate question anyway.